# Second client gets blocked when read from socket inputstream

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I am sending a nonce to the client, however, the first client works fine. When the second client is running, it is blocked after server sent the encrypted nonce.

ReadByte Method:

```
private static void readByte(byte[] byteArray, InputStream byteIn, Socket socket) throws Exception{
   int offset = 0;
   int numRead = 0;
   while (offset < byteArray.length && (numRead = byteIn.read(byteArray, offset, byteArray.length - offset)) >= 0){
        offset += numRead;
    }
    if (offset < byteArray.length) {
        System.out.println("File reception incomplete!");
    }
}
```

EDIT ANSWER
Server:

```
public class Server2 {
    private static final int NumberOfThreads = 5;
    private static ExecutorService executorService =Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(NumberOfThreads);
    private static final int port = 1111;
    private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private static final String privateKeyFile = "privateServer.der";
    private static final String signedCert = "h.crt";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    while(true){
        System.out.println("Server is waiting for connection....");
        try {
            final Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("connection established....");
            Runnable task = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        handleClient(clientSocket);
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
            executorService.execute(task);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private static void handleClient(Socket clientSocket) throws Exception{
    //for getting the byte input and output
    OutputStream byteOut = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
    InputStream byteIn = clientSocket.getInputStream();
    //for getting the string input and output
    PrintWriter stringOut = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(),true);
    BufferedReader stringIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    //print out client msg
    System.out.println(stringIn.readLine());
    stringOut.println("From Server: I am Server!");
    stringOut.flush();
    System.out.println("Sent to client: I am Server!");

    //receive nonce from client
    String nonceLen = stringIn.readLine();
    byte[] nonce = new byte[Integer.parseInt(nonceLen)];
    readByte(nonce,byteIn);
    System.out.println("Nonce Received!");

    //get private key from privateServer.der
    PrivateKey privateKey = getPrivateKey();

    //use private key to initialize the encryption mode
    Cipher RSAEncrypt = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
    RSAEncrypt.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,privateKey);

    //encrypt nonce and send it to the client
    byte[] encryptedNonce = RSAEncrypt.doFinal(nonce);
    stringOut.println(Integer.toString(encryptedNonce.length));
    byteOut.write(encryptedNonce,0,encryptedNonce.length);
    System.out.println(encryptedNonce);
    byteOut.flush();
    System.out.println("Sent to client: encrypted nonce");
    }
}
```

Client:

```
public class Client2 {
private static final String server = "localhost";
private static final int port = 1111;
private static final String filePath = "medianFile.txt";
private static final String fileName = "medianFile.txt";
private static final String CAcert = "CA.crt";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        Socket socket = new Socket(server,port);
        OutputStream byteOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        InputStream byteIn = socket.getInputStream();

        PrintWriter stringOut = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
        BufferedReader stringIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        stringOut.println("Please prove ur identity!");
        stringOut.flush();
        System.out.println("Sent to server: Please prove ur identity!");

        String r1 = stringIn.readLine();
        System.out.println(r1);

//          send nonce
        byte[] nonce = generateNonce();
        if(r1.contains("I am server")){
            stringOut.println(Integer.toString(nonce.length));
            byteOut.write(nonce);
            byteOut.flush();
            System.out.println("Sent to server: nonce sent!");
        }

//          get encrypted nonce from server
        String encryptedNonceLen = stringIn.readLine();
        byte[] encryptedNonceBytes = new byte[Integer.parseInt(encryptedNonceLen)];
        readByte(encryptedNonceBytes,byteIn,socket);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your server multithreaded? Does it `accept()` in a loop?

Comment: If your method is blocking on `byteIn.read()`, it's because it exhausts the bytes available before reading a cumulative total of `byteArray.length` bytes, but the peer socket is not closed.  There is a variety of reasons why that might happen.  It would unblock if more bytes arrived from the peer; that it apparently does not resume eliminates a couple of the possible reasons for blocking.

Comment: @EJP, I used executorservice to handle different threads for the server side, yes the `accept()` is in a while loop.

Comment: Well you're blocking in `read()`, which means the server has stopped sending, or maybe it never started. Further information required, possibly even the server code.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I actually started my second client after first client is finished. So the peer socket is already closed, however, the second client is not able to receive the message sent by the server.

Comment: @RuochenZhang, that doesn't make any sense.  In the first place, only one client can read any given byte sent by the peer -- that consumes it from the stream.  In the second place, if (the local machine recognizes that) the remote peer has closed its socket, then you will *not* block attempting to read from its input stream.  Presenting a [mcve] would greatly improve your chances of getting a useful answer.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Sorry I guess just now I misunderstand the meaning of the peer socket by another client socket.

Comment: No, the 'peer' is the guy at the other end of the connection.